# jQuery Autocomplete with dynamic textfield generated

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

i'm trying to use jquery autocomplete with dynamic textfield generated, autocomplete works but the main problem is i cant populate textfield with name 'alamat' properly. How to set current textfield 'alamat' value properly in autocomplete ?

HTML

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post">
<table id="myTable" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <thead>
        <th>No</th><th>Nama</th><th>Alamat</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<input id="addButton" name="addButton" type="button" value="Add an input" />
<input id="removeButton" name="removeButton" type="button" value="Remove an input" />
</form>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
$(function() {
    var options = {
    source: 'autocomplete.php',
    minLength: 2,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( '#nama_' + counter ).val( ui.item.value );                        
            $( '#alamat_' + counter ).val( ui.item.alamat );
            console.log(ui.item.alamat);    
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( '#nama_' + counter ).val( ui.item.value );                        
            $( '#alamat_' + counter ).val( ui.item.alamat );
            console.log(ui.item.alamat);
        }
    };

    $('input.searchNama').live("keydown.autocomplete", function() {
        $(this).autocomplete(options);
    });

    var addInput = function() {
        if (counter > 1){
            $('input#removeButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        var inputHTML = ' <tr><td><div id="' + counter + '">'+ counter +'</div></td><td><input type="text" id="nama_' +counter + '" class="searchNama" name="nama_' + counter +' " value="" /></td><td><input type="text" id="alamat_' + counter + '" class="searchAlamat" name="alamat_' + counter + '" value="" /></td></tr>';
        $(inputHTML).appendTo("table#myTable tbody");
        $("input.searchNama:last").focus();
        counter++;
    };

    var removeInput = function() {
        counter--;
        if(counter == 1){
            $('input#removeButton').attr('disabled','disabled');
            counter++;
            console.log('Jika Counter == 1 :' + counter);
        } else {
          $("table#myTable tbody tr:last").remove();
          console.log('Jika Counter != 1 :' + counter);
        }
    };

    if (!$("table#myTable tbody").find("input.searchNama").length) {
        addInput();
    }

    $("input#addButton").click(addInput);
    $("input#removeButton").click(removeInput);
});
</script>
```

my autocomplete.php generate JSON result

```
[{
    "label": "Aditya Nursyahbani - Jl. Bratasena IX Blok U6 No. 7",
    "value": "Aditya Nursyahbani",
    "alamat": "Jl. Bratasena IX Blok U6 No. 7"
    },
 {
    "label": "Slamet Aji Pamungkas - Jl. Melati 2 No. 3",
    "value": "Slamet Aji Pamungkas",
    "alamat": "Jl. Melati 2 No. 3"
}]
```

I upload my script on fiddle in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/adit_gudhel/7fCxj/)!

thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('input.searchAlamat').val(ui.item.alamat);`

Your selector will populate all inputs with `class='searchAlamat'` that are contained in the page.

WIthin the `select` callback, `this` will be the current input instance that autocomplete is bound to so you can traverse within the row it is in:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input.searchAlamat').val(ui.item.alamat);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7fCxj/1/)**</kbd>

Note that I removed `focus` functionality

Comment: feel free to approve answer Aditya